# appending a text to the end of nth line without creating a newline

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I have a file `A.txt` and when I try to append a text to end of N<sup>th</sup> line, it's printing by creating a new line, is there any command which will print in the same line without creating a newline?

A.txt

```
hi all       
how r u  
hows going
```

I want to a a string to the line N<sup>th</sup> line ( line 2 in this example)

```
hi all   
how r u friend   
hows going
```

when I try the command I am getting in google, it's coming like below

```
$ cat a.txt
hi all  
how r u   
friend   
hows going
```

Comment: Would you like to repair your existing attempt, or are you open to alternatives? If the former, please include your command in an [edit] to the question. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using `sed` as

```
sed '2s/.*/& friend/' a.txt
```

`2s` indicates that you want to substitute on line 2.  `.*` will capture the entire line while `&` will *print* the line followed by new text.

If you want to update the file at the same time, you can use `-i` option with `sed`.

Comment: It might imply less work for the computer to replace only the end of the line:`sed '2s/$/ friend/' a.txt`

Comment: also can you chekc if you find a solution for this pls : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/647374/remove-a-text-from-the-nth-line-in-a-file

Answer (score 2):

with *awk*:

```
awk 'NR==2{ $0=$0 " friend" }1' infile >output
```

`NR==2` means second line of input, `$0` represent the current input line, `1` at the end, outputs the current input line with any changes made on it or not.