# Remove a text from the nth line in a file

Tags: text-processing, awk, delete

I want to remove a string which is coming from a variable in a line.
`remove_text=' hi'`;

File:

```
kjdkjdkjddkjd
djdk hi sjjsj
jfjf sisj hi
jdkjdk dkjdkdjd hi
hi sksk
```

I want to to delete `hi` from N<sup>th</sup>line ( 2<sup>nd</sup> line in this case.)

File:

```
kjdkjdkjddkjd
djdk sjjsj
jfjf sisj hi
jdkjdk dkjdkdjd hi
hi sksk
```

Comment: You just say what you want. You don't say where you need help, nor what you have tried. Could you [add that to the question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/647374/edit)?

Comment: Should `ship` become `sp`? Include that case in your example and if your "string" can contain regexp metachars then include those test cases too. See [how-do-i-find-the-text-that-matches-a-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65621325/how-do-i-find-the-text-that-matches-a-pattern). Oh and also state/show if your string can contain backslashes as that impacts potential solutions.

Answer (score 1):

It is simple with `sed`.

```
sed '2s/hi//' filename
```

where `2s` substitutes on line `2`, `hi` (the pattern in the first pair of slashes) is the pattern to be replaced, and there is nothing between the second pair of slashes causing the pattern to be deleted.

This command works with variables as well but you have to be careful to enclose the command in double quotes instead of single quotes, as follows

```
remove_text=' hi'
sed "2s/${remove_text}//" filename
```

In case you want to select your line number through a variable, you can do that as well.

```
ln=2
remove_text=' hi'
sed "${ln}s/${remove_text}//" filename
```

Using the option `-i` with `sed` will cause in-place substitution, or update the file.

Comment: and to mention that in that case `${remove_text}` will be treated as regex and will cause sed fail if there has a slash `/` character in it or single/double quote or maybe other characters too, IDK

Comment: see also https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/129063/72456

Answer (score 0):

Using any *awk*:

```
remove_text=' hi';

awk -v rmtxt="$remove_text" '
NR==2{ len=length(rmtxt); ind=index($0, rmtxt);
       print substr($0, 1, ind-1) substr($0, ind+len)
}1' infile
```

or alternatively using the `match()` function (match() treats second arg as regex):

```
awk -v rmpat="$remove_text" '
NR==2{ match($0, rmpat);
       print substr($0, 1, RSTART-1) substr($0, RSTART+RLENGTH)
}1' infile
```

particularly this is to find the first occurrences position of the "*remove_text*" in the second line of input and print two substrings, one before and another after that.

---

if you want to remove all occurrences of that "*remove_text*", do it as following:

```
awk -v rmtxt="$remove_text" 'BEGIN { FS=rmtxt; OFS="" } NR==2{ $1=$1 }1' infile
```

that is defining the "*remove_text*" as the awk's field separator and on the second line of input re-evaluate the input line based on FS/OFS and print the final changes with `1` used.

alternatively, using `gsub()` function, but note that using gsub() will treat the "*remove_text*" value as the *regex* not a literal strings as above solutions does based on string match:

```
awk -v rmpat="$remove_text" 'NR==2{ gsub(rmpat, "") }1' infile
```